# What is the secret behind the economic success of Republic of China (Taiwan)?

Tags: economy

Even though the Republic of China (ROC, also known as Taiwan) is not a member of the United Nations, it has been economically successful. What is the secret behind the economic success of it then?

Comment: sounds like a question for economics.

Comment: If only it wasn't closed...

Comment: economics being closed is probably a good thing for history because there is some overlap interest as this question demonstrates

Comment: Why exactly are you making a n assumption that being a member of the UN is in any way, shape or form correlated to, never mind causes, economic success?

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with the notion that there is "a secret" to economic success.  Although if there were, it would force development economists to stop arguing and obtain productive employment, which would be a good thing....

Comment: not being communist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One word - manufacturing.  Before China was the country of cheap labor it was Taiwan, just as Japan was before Taiwan.  Taiwan built up a lot of manufacturing know-how, and still does so in computer chips and some other respects, it also has many companies that manufacture on the mainland.  The capability of Taiwan being able to do this also coincides with its economic system, which as differentiated from the Maoist-Communist system on the mainland, allowed entrepreneurship to blossom as Japanese and US investment came into Taiwan.

For a recent economic overview on Taiwan's [GDP Growth](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/taiwan/gdp-growth):

> The Gross Domestic Product (GDP) in Taiwan expanded 1.06 percent in
>   the first quarter of 2012 over the previous quarter. Historically,
>   from 1981 until 2012, Taiwan GDP Growth Rate averaged 1.4000 Percent
>   reaching an all time high of 5.6400 Percent in December of 1990 and a
>   record low of -5.0700 Percent in December of 2008. The Gross Domestic
>   Product (GDP) growth rate provides an aggregated measure of changes in
>   value of the goods and services produced by an economy. Taiwan is an
>   industrialized, developed country, just off the coast of China.
>   Taiwan's economy, one of the "Four Asian Tigers", is export-oriented
>   and specialized in production of electronics and machinery. In fact,
>   Taiwan is one of the world's largest suppliers of computer chips, LCD
>   panels, DRAM computer memory, networking equipment, and consumer
>   electronics. Textile production, although already in decline, is
>   another major industrial export sector. This page includes a chart
>   with historical data for Taiwan GDP Growth Rate.

And for a historical review of Industrial Development in Taiwan you can review [Digital Taiwan's](http://culture.teldap.tw/culture/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1358%3ahistory-of-industrial-development-in-taiwan-part-i&catid=158%3aarchives-and-databases&Itemid=210) overview which puts it better than I can to cover their many areas of Production.

Edited:
So I guess if you ask for the Why then you can look up the [Taiwan Miracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan_Miracle) where although land reform moved labor to Urban Centers, providing for a cheap factory worker group you also have increased US Aid which

> created a massive industrial infrastructure, communications, and developed the educational system

Without that industrial infrastructure you could not have the manufacturing take off that the country had, in my opinion.  Again the economic system plays a very important role, Capitalist markets on Taiwan allowed it to grow and become a manufacturing/exporter with a cheap, educated labor pool.  Since many of these reforms, or a cheap manufacturing workforce, never took place on the Mainland until Deng Xiaoping began reforms that set the stage for the China we have today.  As noted on [Suite 101's Chinese History page](http://suite101.com/article/causes-of-chinas-economic-growth-a115276) Deng began reforms in 1978 called the

> gaige kaifang, or “reform and opening up.” These were intended to jumpstart China’s economy and caused rapid economic growth in China.

Once the commune system was abolished and the markets began to open then China became a place to invest and manufacture in.  There is a good [overview of Deng's reforms](http://factsanddetails.com/china.php?itemid=79) that note them in detail.  But without the market forces that began to operate on the mainland in agriculture and industry, just as they did in Taiwan previously, then China never would have taken over.

Although considering the state of Taiwan for the past 10 years I am not sure you can call them an economic success anymore, considering their marginalization within the UN world body they do pretty well.  As to the marginalization in numerous world bodies that is another question in itself that deserves its own answer.  And yes I know they still do well as a county, my wife comes from Taiwan so I keep an eye as to what is going on there.

Comment: Wikipedia cites other reasons such as a focus on education and land reform. What do your sources say on that? I also don't think their lack of influence in international organisations is much of an issue since major importing economies have been perfectly willing to trade with them.

Comment: While wikipedia is a good source for many things, its not the only one.  Education and land reform are a good basis for the country but don't create a vibrant economy on their own.  Taiwan was a manufacturing exporter, and still is in some areas such as computer chips, which allows it to work on the international markets.

Comment: Of course the next question would be why Taiwan developed into such a manufacturing powerhouse, while mostly the same people on the mainland stagnated for two generations (as they had for quite a few more generations before the split). IOW: I think you are displaying a symptom of their success, not the cause.

Comment: @ MichaelF, I agree with T.E.D..

Comment: @T.E.D. Guess who America supported...Taiwan. I'd guess, though I've not no real evidence to back it up, that is why Taiwan grew faster in the short run.

Comment: @T.E.D. I think we know why that would be, but its entirely a different question.  Although if you take Japan's example and look at how they became an economic success in the same vein, then note when Taiwan took over and who took over from Taiwan in some areas it's basic manufacturing capitalism where you look for the cheapest means of production in a country that can support it.  But I am a Historian not an Economist.

Comment: @T.E.D. Added some more material, but not sure what Why you are looking for.  Communism on the Mainland would have prevented China from advancing more until Deng, but maybe I am missing what you are getting at.

Comment: @MichaelF - that last comment was the most relevant. Pad it with sources and it could be its own indepenent answer.

Comment: @T.E.D.: You are partly right that it's describing symptoms, not causes, but the causes are always the same: Reasonable, pragmatic free market economics. The question really is what is preventing other countries from being as successful (and the answer is  always war, socialism, corruption, in that order).

Comment: @DVK True, I wasn't originally going to, but I guess this one has become a compare/contrast with China though I never saw the original question that way.

Comment: @Russell actually, you might say instead that the reason which later brought success to Taiwan, is the same reason why Taiwan had US support.

Answer (score 1):

One East Asian economic miracle occurred in Japan. A few years later 4 more occurred in S. Korea, Taiwan, Singapore and Hong Kong.

All of these countries and Hong Kong had a few things in common.

All had spent significant time being governed by Either Japan or England. None were democratic and so were able to avoid the temptations of socialism. All managed to avoid a communist revolution for various reasons. All were cultures that prized education.

As for Taiwan in particular, they were rebuilding their wealth, not just creating it from scratch. The Japanese has built infrastructure and schools while ruling Taiwan. Just before WWII Taiwan was the wealthiest region in Asia outside of the Japanese home islands.  After the war the Chinese looted Taiwan, introduced corruption and caused unrest, but the human capital (an educated experienced workforce) and much of the infrastructure survived.